# How to react to an activity with an emoji

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I'm using Bot Builder v4 but I can't find the API to post an emoji reaction. Is there such an API?

`ITurnContext<IMessageActivity>` seems to have methods to send, update and delete activities. No methods to post a reaction.

The [sample pages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/25.message-reaction/Bots/MessageReactionBot.cs) only offer an example of how to receive events for reactions. No example of how to post a reaction programmatically.

For example, here's a `:heart:` reaction, supported by most chat platforms (Slack, Teams, WhatsApp, etc.). How can a bot post such a reaction?

[image]

Comment: "to react to a message with an emoji" is a bit ambiguous. Are you wanting to respond to a message that has an emoji contained within it? Or respond with an emoji to a message? Also, which version of the SDK are you using and what client will your bot be used on (Web Chat, Teams, Facebook, etc.)?

Comment: I want to respond with an emoji reaction (not a new message). I'm using the WhatsApp community adapter, but the question is more general. I want to know if there is such an API in the SDK.

Comment: I changed the wording and added a screenshot to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActivityHandler` class has a few methods that may serve your needs. They are [`OnMessageReactionActivityAsync()`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L273), [`OnReactionsAddedAsync()`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L307), and [`OnReactionsRemovedAsync()`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L333). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the WhatsApp adapter to speak to how message data from WhatsApp is returned. When working with ABS connector channels in Azure that data is returned in the `activity.channelData` property. The connector does the dirty work of converting a client/service event into an `Event` activity type in BotFramework, for example.

The adapter may or may not do that. If it does, then great. Check these APIs and see which one it comes thru. It's possible, however, that all WhatsApp messages are treated as `Message` activity types and it will be up to you to read the channel data. Then you can either call another activity handler or just handle it where it is.

Be aware that one API may, unexpectedly, be the sole recipient of all incoming messages. I don't remember which client I was working with and this was in JS, but my bot would only catch reactions in `OnReactsAdded()`. This was true for both reactions added and reactions removed.

Another consideration: If the adapter doesn't quite work the way you need it to, don't be afraid to clone the repo and add the required functionality.

Comment: This does not answer my question. These methods can be used to handle an emoji reaction event. My question is if there is an API to post an emoji reaction myself. For example, in `OnMessageActivityAsync()`, can I react with a heart emoji on a message?